# Why is the API response text empty when I create and use the XMLGttpRequest inside a function

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to grab data from an API, if i create the `XMLHttpRequest` and use `.open()` and `.send()` outside of a function it works fine. But, when it's created and used inside the function it logs nothing. If I use JSON.parse() on it then it throws an error " Unexpected end of JSON input" and shows the JSON file as being empty so it isn't connecting to the right file. Does anyone know why?

**Working Code:**

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const input = document.querySelector("#name-input");
const URL = "https://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/search?q=wooden+door";

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", URL, true);
xhr.send()

form.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (xhr.status = 200) {
        const data = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(data);

    }


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>VA API</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>V&A API</h1>

    <form action="">
        <label for="object-name">Object Name / Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="object-name" id="name-input">

        <label for="origin">Place of Origin</label>
        <input type="text" name="origin" id="origin-input">

        <label for="earliest-year">Earliest Year (YYYY)</label>
        <input type="text" name="earliest-year" id="earliest-year-input">

        <label for="latest-year">Latest Year (YYYY)</label>
        <input type="text" name="latest-year" id="latest-year-input">

        <label for="artist">Artist / Maker</label>
        <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist-input">

        <label for="materials">Material / Techniques</label>
        <input type="text" name="materials" id="materials-input">

        <label for="obj-num">Museum Object Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="obj-num" id="onj-num-input">

        <label for="loc">Current Location</label>
        <input type="text" name="loc" id="loc-input">


        <button id="search-btn">Search</button>
        <button id="clear-btn">Clear Form</button>

    </form>
    <!-- Form Buttons -->

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
<style>
    input {
        margin: 1vw;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

**Not working code**

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const input = document.querySelector("#name-input");

const URL = "https://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/search?after=2000"

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();



    e.preventDefault()
    if (xhr.status = 200) {
        const data = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(data);
        xhr.open("GET", URL, true);
        xhr.send()
    }


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>VA API</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>V&A API</h1>

    <form action="">
        <label for="object-name">Object Name / Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="object-name" id="name-input">

        <label for="origin">Place of Origin</label>
        <input type="text" name="origin" id="origin-input">

        <label for="earliest-year">Earliest Year (YYYY)</label>
        <input type="text" name="earliest-year" id="earliest-year-input">

        <label for="latest-year">Latest Year (YYYY)</label>
        <input type="text" name="latest-year" id="latest-year-input">

        <label for="artist">Artist / Maker</label>
        <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist-input">

        <label for="materials">Material / Techniques</label>
        <input type="text" name="materials" id="materials-input">

        <label for="obj-num">Museum Object Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="obj-num" id="onj-num-input">

        <label for="loc">Current Location</label>
        <input type="text" name="loc" id="loc-input">


        <button id="search-btn">Search</button>
        <button id="clear-btn">Clear Form</button>

    </form>
    <!-- Form Buttons -->

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
<style>
    input {
        margin: 1vw;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: I would think that here `if (xhr.status = 200) {` you really want `if (xhr.status === 200) {`. The former attempts to set the value of `xhr.status` to `200` while the latter checks `xhr.status` for a value of `200`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with your code is that you are trying to access the status of the response before even sending the request, `xhr.open` and `xhr.send` should be outside of the if block.  And even after you send the request you'll have to wait until the response settles to check for the status code, it's asynchronous operation.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          const data = xhr.responseText;
          console.log(data);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", URL, true);
    xhr.send();
    
    e.preventDefault();

})
```

**UPDATE**(To incorporate your question in the comment):

To change the `URL` depending on input value, change the `const` declaration of the `URL` to `let` or `var`, and inside the event handler use either an `if` or `switch` statement to reassign the `URL` to a different value.

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const input = document.querySelector("#name-input");
let URL = "https://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/search?q=wooden+door";

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        const data = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(data);
      }
  };

  //If you are going to check multiple values against the input value, the 'switch' statement is more handy
  switch(input.value) {
    case 'necklace': URL = 'vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/…'; break;
    case value2: URL = urr2; break;
    case value3: URL = urr3; break;
    //you would normally need a default expression here, but it's not necessary for this specific case as the URL already has a default value.
  }

  //optionally: if you check a single value, it's more readable to use if statement
  if(input.value === 'necklace')  URL = 'vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/…';

  xhr.open("GET", URL, true);
  xhr.send();
  
  e.preventDefault();

})
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! Also, how could I edit the code to allow me to modify the URL once the event listener is fired. For example of the  user inputs "necklace" into the "object name" section, I would want the URL to be: http://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject/search?objectnamesearch=necklace

Comment: the "object name" section is `name-input`?

Comment: yeah, sorry should've specified that

Comment: this would work if i knew every option and what they user will input, but how can i make so that the user can input anything and it logs what they search whether it finds something or not?

Comment: @OliKnight, that sounds entirely different from the original question. please post it as a separate question with more clarification on what you want.